# Group By and Sum for this query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to group by `OrderNumber`, `Product`, `ConveyanceID` and `Trip` for this below query but I want to retrieve all these columns and finally `sum(Volume)`.

So for an example something like this

```
SELECT 
    OD.[Customer]
    ,OD.[OrderNumber] 'Order#'
    ,OD.[Shipper]
    ,OD.[Product]
    ,OD.[Dock] 'Dock/Track'
    ,OD.[Lines] 'Berth/Position'
    ,[TAMS].[fnc_GetDelayCountByOrderNumber](OD.OrderNumber) 'Delays' 
    ,OD.[ScheduledArrival] 'Sched .Arrival'
    ,OD.ActiveCheckPointStatus 'Active CheckPoint'
    ,OD.[CheckPointStatus] 'CheckPoint Status'
    ,OD.[ContractNumber]
    ,OD.[Direction]
    ,SUM(OD.[Volume]) 'Volume'
    ,OD.[PreviousCheckPointStatus]
    ,OD.[CheckPointType]
    ,OD.[SourceContainer]
    ,OD.[DestinationContainer]
    ,OD.[UnitsOfMeasure]
    ,OD.ConveyanceID
    ,OD.TripId
    ,OD.NumberOfConveyance
FROM 
    TAMS.OrderDetail OD
WHERE 
    OrderNumber = 8394
GROUP BY 
    PRODUCT, Ordernumber, ConveyanceID, TripID
```

How can I do that?

```
SELECT 
    OD.[Customer]
    ,OD.[OrderNumber] 'Order#'
    ,OD.[Shipper]
    ,OD.[Product]
    ,OD.[Dock] 'Dock/Track'
    ,OD.[Lines] 'Berth/Position'
    ,[TAMS].[fnc_GetDelayCountByOrderNumber](OD.OrderNumber) 'Delays' 
    ,OD.[ScheduledArrival] 'Sched .Arrival'
    ,OD.ActiveCheckPointStatus 'Active CheckPoint'
    ,OD.[CheckPointStatus] 'CheckPoint Status'
    ,OD.[ContractNumber]
    ,OD.[Direction]
    ,OD.[Volume]
    ,OD.[PreviousCheckPointStatus]
    ,OD.[CheckPointType]
    ,OD.[SourceContainer]
    ,OD.[DestinationContainer]
    ,OD.[UnitsOfMeasure]
    ,OD.ConveyanceID
    ,OD.TripId
    ,OD.NumberOfConveyance
FROM 
    TAMS.OrderDetail OD
WHERE  
    OrderNumber = 8394
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to GROUP BY those four columns then do you need to select all of the other columns?

Comment: yes I want to groupby for those four columns and select all other columns

Comment: And what happens if one of those other columns that aren't in the group by have different values?  So, for instance if we had... one user with id 1.  We group by that.  But lets say we are saving the users actions.  If we group by the users id then what happens with the different actions?  You need to group by that too.  Does that make sense or should I give a better example?  Point is, there is a reason why you cannot display things that are not in the groupby.  If you can get away without using the extra columns then the solution is pretty simple.

Comment: It does not matter. I want to retrieve all the records whose data is same for Product, OrderNumber, ConveyanceID, TripID

Comment: @user1030181 Please show a sample expected result.  Describing what you want in words only leads to confusion and frustration.

Comment: Okay in above image I have 4 results which have same order number which is `8394`, Same conveyanceID which is `178047` and same tripid which is `211583` but different products LIKE `LIMESTONE`and `AGGREGATE` but now all i need is to group by ordernumber, product, conveyanceid, tripid so that i can get result of only two records of limestone or aggregate products but in results i want all those other columns also

Comment: Ok, if you only group by those 4 columns, and there are two different values for [Direction], which value should the query return?

Comment: This looks like a bad database design. You obviously expect the values for all other columns (direction, contractnumber, etc.) to be the same per product, but if so, why do you store them multifold?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.   Every column in the query has to be either in the GROUP BY, or an aggregate function.

Answer (score 1):

One option you can do is using a `SUM()` with an `OVER()` `PARTITION` on those fields:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        OD.[Customer]
        ,OD.[OrderNumber] 'Order#'
        ,OD.[Shipper]
        ,OD.[Product]
        ,OD.[Dock] 'Dock/Track'
        ,OD.[Lines] 'Berth/Position'
        ,[TAMS].[fnc_GetDelayCountByOrderNumber](OD.OrderNumber) 'Delays' 
        ,OD.[ScheduledArrival] 'Sched .Arrival'
        ,OD.ActiveCheckPointStatus 'Active CheckPoint'
        ,OD.[CheckPointStatus] 'CheckPoint Status'
        ,OD.[ContractNumber]
        ,OD.[Direction]
        ,OD.[Volume]
        ,OD.[PreviousCheckPointStatus]
        ,OD.[CheckPointType]
        ,OD.[SourceContainer]
        ,OD.[DestinationContainer]
        ,OD.[UnitsOfMeasure]
        ,OD.ConveyanceID
        ,OD.TripId
        ,OD.NumberOfConveyance
        ,SUM(OD.Volume) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNumber, Product, ConveyanceID, Trip) As SumOfVolume
FROM    TAMS.OrderDetail OD
WHERE   OrderNumber= 8394
```

The caveat of doing it this way is that this `SUM()` value will appear on every record, though.

However, if you don't need the extra fields, you can simply do this instead:

```
SELECT  OrderNumber 'Order#',
        Product, 
        ConveyanceID,
        Trip,
        SUM(Volume) As SumOfVolume
FROM    TAMS.OrderDetail OD
WHERE   OrderNumber= 8394
GROUP BY OrderNumber, Product, ConveyanceID, Trip
```

Comment: I want to do group by for whole query and find sum of the volume

Comment: In above query you are just doing for volume column it does not work

Comment: @user1030181 How doesn't it work?  And I've updated the answer to add an alternate query without the additional fields.

Comment: You are not understanding my question I want to get all other columns but to have group by with these columns `OrderNumber, Product, ConveyanceID, Trip`

Comment: @user1030181 I understand that - what I don't understand is how the first solution "does not work" for you.

Comment: yes it did not work i want to get those records whose product, ordernumber, conveyanceid, tripid are same

Comment: @user1030181 I'm not following...  Do you want to get a *single record* per grouping of those fields with the SUM *in addition to pulling all of the other fields?*  I really don't know what you're expecting the database to return, as this is not possible, since those extra fields hold different values in them, they will need the extra records being returned.  If this is the case that you only want *one* record per group, then you really don't care about the other fields, so the second query would satisfy your needs.  Otherwise, the first query will.

Comment: @user1030181 If you are expecting something different from either of these solutions, please update your question to show your desired query result, because I have no idea what you're asking for.

Comment: Okay in above image I have 4 results which have same order number which is 8394, Same conveyanceID which is 178047 and same tripid which is 211583 but different products LIKE LIMESTONEand AGGREGATE but now all i need is to group by ordernumber, product, conveyanceid, tripid so that i can get result of only two records of limestone or aggregate products but in results i want all those other columns also

Comment: @user1030181 I can't see all of the columns in your table, but are all of the other values the same for all of the records?

Comment: Updated answer - I can't see all of your columns in the screenshot, but perhaps a `DISTINCT` would help you.  Otherwise, you can't get down to a single column per group with a large number of additional columns with different data in them.  That's just not how databases work.

Comment: @user1030181 Please read. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx .  Anything in the group by has to be inside of an AGGREGATE function or in the select statement as is.  When you want to do the four columns in the group by you can not get the rest of the results.  Are you saying you want one row for each LIMESTONE and AGGREGATE?  How would you except that when the rest of the columns are different.  There is a reason it won't let you do it.