# How to retrieve those records whose data is same

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query below,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
    OD.[Customer]
    ,OD.[OrderNumber] 'Order#'
    ,OD.[Shipper]
    ,OD.[Product]
    ,OD.[Dock] 'Dock/Track'
    ,OD.[Lines] 'Berth/Position'
    ,[TAMS].[fnc_GetDelayCountByOrderNumber](OD.OrderNumber) 'Delays' 
    ,OD.[ScheduledArrival] 'Sched .Arrival'
    ,OD.ActiveCheckPointStatus 'Active CheckPoint'
    ,OD.[CheckPointStatus] 'CheckPoint Status'
    ,OD.[ContractNumber]
    ,OD.[Direction]
    ,OD.[Volume]
    ,OD.[PreviousCheckPointStatus]
    ,OD.[CheckPointType]
    ,OD.[SourceContainer]
    ,OD.[DestinationContainer]
    ,OD.[UnitsOfMeasure]
    ,OD.ConveyanceID
    ,OD.TripId
    ,OD.NumberOfConveyance
    ,OD.Volume
    FROM TAMS.OrderDetail OD
    WHERE OrderNumber= 8394
```

This query returns 4 records

[image]

This query has same ordernumber (8394), same conveyanceid(178047), same tripid(211583). But only different is product (AGGREGATE, LIMESTONE)

So instead of showing four records how can i show like just two records of different products (Aggregate, Limestone).

It should look like

[image]

Comment: Never heard of `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I dont want to use group by because it will group by on all columns

Comment: You _can_ group by multiple columns. Since you have omitted some columns(like `Volume)` in the desired result that also seems to be desired.

Comment: Make the sample simpler and use text, we cant copy paste from picture. And we cant compare data from output if they are that small or in two different pages. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I just omitted volume but does not make any difference if its there or not

Comment: You already asked this question here: [Group By and Sum for this query in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790248/group-by-and-sum-for-this-query-in-sql-server).  I'm voting to close this question.  You don't need two open questions asking the same thing.

Comment: This is not for me but a lot of people have helped you here.  It's good form to uptick them for taking their time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are requesting DISTINCT VOLUME along with everything else, if you are going to keep the distinct in your query then you will need to remove the volume column because as long as those volumes are different the query will return those four distinct rows. Only other option would be to group by the customer, order, etc and select the max/min/avg volume, but I can't tell by your question whether or not you need to have the volume returned. I noticed VOLUME isn't included in your second screenshot, so maybe you don't need it?

Comment: i need it but i just took it off while i was testing something